# Remove urls from strings

Tags: r, url, replace, gsub

I have the following string, stored in the object `sentence`:

```
sentence <- "aazdlubtirol: RT @tradeDayTrades: sister articles \"$AAPL Dancing in a Burning Room\" January 2013  http://t.co/tkuCRfLy  \" $AAPL vs $AAPL \"  August 2011 http://t.co/863HkVjn"
```

I am trying to use gsub to remove urls beginning with `http`:

`sentence <- gsub('http.*','',sentence)`

However, it replaces everything after `http`:

`aazdlubtirol: RT @tradeDayTrades: sister articles \"$AAPL Dancing in a Burning Room\" January 2013`

What I want is:

`aazdlubtirol: RT @tradeDayTrades: sister articles \"$AAPL Dancing in a Burning Room\" January 2013    \" $AAPL vs $AAPL \"  August 2011`

I am trying to clean up the urls so if a string includes `http` I want to remove the url. I found some solutions but they are not helping me.

Comment: Add a space to your replacement group:  `gsub('http.* ', '', sentence)`.

Comment: @Justin great answer I tried `gsub('http.*\\s', '', sentence)` but it doesn't work.  Maybe you could add yours as an answer.

Comment: I find it strange that `\\s` wouldn't work where a single space does.

Comment: @Justin I tried using space but it doesn't work.

Comment: @TylerRinker see my answer, neither work for the case where the url is the last thing in the string.

Comment: @Justin I want to clean the tweet from url's so what I am trying to do is use gsub and if the string consists of http delete it. Also in this tweet there will be multiple links. I tried the space but it delete everything after first url. Not sure what to do. Is there any easy way to delete urls in R

Comment: You made your question overly complicated. If I understand correctly, what you mean to ask is: "How can I use regex to remove all urls from a string?".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a space to your replacement group:

```
gsub('http.* *', '', sentence)
```

Or using `\\s` which is regex for space:

```
gsub('http.*\\s*', '', sentence)
```

As per the comment, `.*` will match anything and regular expressions are greedy.  Instead we should match one or more non-whitespace character any number of times followed by zero or more spaces:

```
gsub('http\\S+\\s*', '', sentence)
```

Comment: Note that `.*` will also match white space... if you mean to have zero or more non-white-space characters followed by zero or mode white space characters, you really need to use: `gsub('http\\S*\\s*', '', sentence)`

Comment: Tried it:sentence
[1] "traderclubtirol: RT AnniDayTrades: sister articles \"$AAPL Dancing in a Burning Room\" January 2013  http://t.co/tkuCRfLy  \" $AAPL vs $AAPL \"  August 2011 http://t.co/863HkVjn"
> sentence = gsub('http.*\\s*', '', sentence)
> sentence
[1] "traderclubtirol: RT AnniDayTrades: sister articles \"$AAPL Dancing in a Burning Room\" January 2013  "
> 
> but it deletes everything after first url

Comment: @Justin: you can go one step further and match urls at the end of the string with `gsub('http\\S+\\s*|http\\S+$', '', sentence)`

Comment: @jbaums `\\s*` will match 0 or more spaces, so it should still catch it.  You could use `'\\s*http\\S+\\s*'` to get rid of the left over trailing space too..

Comment: Sorry, yep just noticed that.

Comment: I think `gsub("(http[^ ]*)", "", sentence)` works too.

Comment: @TylerRinker: Nice one, but the parentheses around http aren't necessary.